Authorization error while creating a new MongoDB database dynamically using PHP MongoDB driver
I am trying to create new mongoDB database in runtime, via php/Laravel code:-
Initially, I had created the mongodb user via mongoshell like this:-
use test_mongodb;

db.createUser({user: "test_mongodbu", pwd: "test_password", roles: [{ role: "dbOwner", db: "test_mongodb"}]})

In my env file, I have the data like this:-
MONGODB_CONNECTION=mongodb
MONGODB_HOST=localhost
MONGODB_PORT=27017
MONGODB_DATABASE=test_mongodb
MONGODB_USERNAME=test_mongodbu
MONGODB_PASSWORD=test_password
MONGODB_MASTER_DATABASE=test_mongodb

I am dynamically creating a new db via php MongoDrive like this:-
use MongoDB\Client as MongoClient;
use MongoDB\Driver\Manager as MongoManager;
use MongoDB\Driver\Command as MongoCommand;

$databaseName      = $username; // 'little_buds'
$collectionName    = 'test'; 
$connectionString  = 'mongodb://' . env('MONGODB_USERNAME') . ':' . env('MONGODB_PASSWORD') . '@' . env('MONGODB_HOST') . ':' . env('MONGODB_PORT') . '/?authSource=' . env('MONGODB_DATABASE');

$client     = new MongoClient($connectionString);  // Connect to MongoDB server
$manager    = new MongoManager($connectionString); 
$database   = $client->$databaseName;              // Dynamically create a database
$command    = array(
                'grantRolesToUser'  => env('MONGODB_USERNAME'),
                'roles'             => array(
                                        array(
                                            'role'  => 'dbOwner', 
                                            'db'    => $databaseName
                                        )
                                    )
            ); // command to grant the role of 'dbOwner' to existing user test_mongodbu

$manager->executeCommand(env('MONGODB_DATABASE'), new MongoCommand($command)); // executing the command
$database->$collectionName->insertOne(array('key' => 'value'));  // Insert a document into a collection

My idea is to create a new db (say little_buds) and grant the role of 'dbOwner' to the already existing test_mongodbu user of database test_mongodb
I am getting this error-
Not authorized on little_roses to execute command { insert: "test", ordered: true, $db: "little_buds", lsid: { id: UUID("d9ca3d5f-4299-4545-a487-7c565bc59ed4") } }

WHat am I doing wrong? Do I need to update the permission of the user- Like from roles: [{ role: "dbOwner", db: "lppportal_mongodb"}] to roles: [{ role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "lppportal_mongodb"}]?

Does this answer your question? Authentication failure while trying to save to mongodb

@WernfriedDomscheit No it doesn't.

Are you sure? In which database did you create the user?

That is not an authentication error, that is an authorization error.  Check the mongod log for that connection, you should find an "authentication success" log entry that will tell you which user/database was authenticated.  Also note the database name is "little_buds", was your user granted any privileges on that database?

@Joe I have modified my question a bit. Please check

In principle you would need to create the user with these roles:
use test_mongodb;
db.createUser({
   user: "test_mongodbu", 
   pwd: "test_password", 
   roles: [
      { role: "dbOwner", db: "test_mongodb"},
      { role: "readWrite", db: "lppportal_mongodb"}
   ]
})

However, this does not work, see Manage Users and Roles

Except for roles created in the admin database, a role can only
include privileges that apply to its database and can only inherit
from other roles in its database.
A role created in the admin database can include privileges that apply
to the admin database, other databases or to the cluster resource, and
can inherit from roles in other databases as well as the admin
database.

You must create the user in admin database, for example
db.getSiblingDB('admin').createUser({
   user: "test_mongodbu", 
   pwd: "test_password", 
   roles: [
      { role: "dbOwner", db: "test_mongodb"},
      { role: "readWrite", db: "lppportal_mongodb"}
   ]
})

In this case, your connection string must be like this:
 $connectionString  = 'mongodb://' 
   . env('MONGODB_USERNAME') . ':' . env('MONGODB_PASSWORD') 
   . '@' . env('MONGODB_HOST') . ':' . env('MONGODB_PORT') 
   . '/' . env('MONGODB_DATABASE') . '?authSource=admin';

  -> 'mongodb://test_mongodbu:test_password@localhost:27017/test_mongodb?authSource=admin'

